# Use css transition on multiple elements at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason, when trying to animate two elements at the same time(based on max-height) the transition always happens one at a time, first one element and when it finishes it's transition the other element starts it's transition.
Please see this example i have build on js bin to see the phenomenon.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".b").css("max-height", "500px");
}, 500);

setTimeout(function () {
    $(".b").css("max-height", "0");
    $(".c").css("max-height", "500px");
}, 2000);
```

http://jsbin.com/riperifoku/edit?html,js,output

I would appreciate any help in mitigating this mystery

Comment: Cannot work out why this is doing this, I may be overlooking it. I did however implement a not particularly nice work around by just setting a `500ms` timeout on the `.c` transition: `setTimeout(function() { $(".c").css("max-height", "500px"); }, 500);`

Comment: @rotman what's your actually expecting out put.?

Comment: Is there any limitation that you can't use CSS keyframe animation?

Comment: We cannot say unless you show us how the transitions are defined (duration etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem or not. but If you want to initiate css transition of two elements at the same time then see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pscqma7/)

Basically you should not put two setTimeout functions. both CSS transitions should be done within single setTimeout function like follows

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".b").css("max-height", "500px");
    $(".c").css("max-height", "500px");
}, 1000);
```

**Updated Answer**

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pscqma7/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    background:blue;
}
.b .box {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    transition: height 2s ease;
}
.c .box{
     background: red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    transition: height 2s ease;
}
```

**JS**

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $(".b .box").css("height", "10");
  $(".c .box").css("height", "200px");
}, 1000);


setTimeout(function () {
  $(".b .box").css("height", "200");
  $(".c .box").css("height", "10px");
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, i m expecting to see div b shrinking down to 0px while c div will expend to 500px, the proble, is that the two transitions happen one after the other and not simultaneity as i want it. i want div b to shrink and div c to expend at the same time. the first set time out is just to show the change in a more obvious way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

hi are you looking like this..??
as i understand i think this would be what you want

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $(".b").css("max-height", "500px");
  $(".c").css("max-height", "500px");
}, 500);


setTimeout(function () {
  $(".b").css("max-height", "0");  
}, 2000);
```

```css
    .box { background: red; height: 200px; width: 200px; margin: 15px; }
    .a { height: 500px; width: 500px; background: blue; }
    
    .b, .c { max-height: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: max-height 1s; transition-delay: 0; }
```

```html
  <div class="a">
    
    <div class="b">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

and here is the working demo of this code

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j6yo6orh/)**

Comment: imagine 2 div's, one is 5px in height and two is 50px in height, i wish for div one to transit into 50px in height and div two to reduce in height to 5px and i want both divs to transit at the same time...